# Custom bot to temporarily add roles in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey so my i want my bot to temporarily assign a role when the client (user) uses a certain word. I have the code for the words ready but i dont have any clue on how to temprole them the role.

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
const swearWords = ["xyz"];
if( swearWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) {
  message.reply("Oh no you said a bad word!!!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<member>.roles.add()` method to add the role and assign a timeout function to remove the role after a specific time using `<member>.roles.remove()`

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
const swearWords = ["xyz"];
if( swearWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) {
  message.reply("Oh no you said a bad word!!!");
  const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == 'rolenamehere'); // finding the role
  message.member.roles.add(role); // adding the role
  setTimeout(() => message.member.roles.remove(role), 3000); // second param is time in milliseconds
});
```